# Anyone explain me the working of this code

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This program shows original image, scaled image and cropped image. but this code is how to scaled image. I cannot understand the working and logic of this code. Can anyone here tell me how this code works? thanks in advance.

```
[row,col] = size(lena);
Scale_Rows = 2*row;
Scale_Cols = 2*col;

Scale_image = zeros(Scale_Rows,Scale_Cols);


for i= 1:row 

    for j = 1:col
        Scale_image(i*2,j*2) = lena(i,j);
    end
end

conv_mask = [ 0.25 0.5 0.25; 0.5   1  0.5;  0.25 0.5 0.25];
fin_lena = lena;



figure;
imshow(fin_lena);
title('Scaled Image');
```

Answer (score 2):

The code here starts by doubling the size of the image in terms of the coordinates:

```
for i= 1:row 
    for j = 1:col
        Scale_image(i*2,j*2) = lena(i,j);
    end
end
```

So if the original image was

```
A B
C D
```

It then becomes:

```
A X B X
X X X X
C X D X
X X X X
```

Where `X` is an empty pixel.

The code then fills in (interpolates) the empty pixels by taking a combination of the pixels around it according to this:

```
conv_mask = [ 0.25 0.5 0.25; 
               0.5   1  0.5; 
             0.25 0.5 0.25];
```

So that means that you take a weight of 1 for the pixel you are currently on, 0.5 for any pixel thats immediately above or to the side and 0.25 for a nearby diagonal pixel. After doing this for all the pixels the gaps are then filled in. By filling the blank gaps like this you end up with a better looking picture than you get by just doubling the original pixels.

Comment: @shiny Ray Don't forget to accept the answer that best solved your problem.

Comment: This is assuming that the line `fin_lena = lena;` is actually supposed to be something more like `fin_lena = conv2(Scale_image, conv_mask, 'same')`

Comment: @Dan, the question got significantly edited after I answered.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a very simple 2x upsampling routine:

- insert zeroes between all samples to get 2x image
- apply simple 3x3 low-pass filter to interpolate